# Gtkglext and gtkglarea gtk3 windows does not work

Tags: opengl, gtk3, vtk

I need to get working gtk3 with vtk6.
Ive just built (after some effort) gtkglext for gtk3.
Later I built vtkmm1.2 with the win32 patches and I do not see vtk widget.
Due to this, I discovered I cant see any draw in the gtkglext examples.

On the other side, Ive tried the excellent example of gtkglarea (the new, gtk built in one ) with plain opengl from https://www.bassi.io/articles/2015/02/17/using-opengl-with-gtk/
and I get no draw because "fb setup not supported".

It seems the framebuffer is complete, checking gtkglarea.c.
How can i solve this?
Anyone have been able to draw something in gtk with opengl, for windows?

This is the simplest code i've made,and i'm getting the mentioned error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOWqU.jpg), and adapting the signals to the new built in GtkGLArea ("render" instead of "draw")

```
#include <math.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//#include <gtkgl/gtkglarea.h> //LUCIANO, gtkglarea is built in now
#include <gtk/gtkglarea.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

gint init(GtkWidget *widget)
{
  /* OpenGL functions can be called only if make_current returns true */
  gtk_gl_area_make_current(GTK_GL_AREA(widget));
    {
      GtkAllocation allocation;
      gtk_widget_get_allocation (widget, &allocation);
      glViewport(0, 0, allocation.width, allocation.height);
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      glOrtho(0,100, 100,0, -1,1);
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
      glLoadIdentity();
    }
  return TRUE;
}


/* When widget is exposed it's contents are redrawn. */
gboolean draw (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
  /* OpenGL functions can be called only if make_current returns true */
  gtk_gl_area_make_current(GTK_GL_AREA(widget));
    {

      /* Draw simple triangle */
      glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      glColor3f(1,1,1);
      glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
      glVertex2f(10,10);
      glVertex2f(10,90);
      glVertex2f(90,90);
      glEnd();

      /* Swap backbuffer to front */
      //ggla_area_swap_buffers(GGLA_AREA(widget));
      gtk_gl_area_attach_buffers(GTK_GL_AREA(widget));

    }

  return TRUE;
}

/* When glarea widget size changes, viewport size is set to match the new size */
gint reshape(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventConfigure *event)
{
  /* OpenGL functions can be called only if make_current returns true */
  //if (ggla_area_make_current(GTK_GL_AREA(widget)))
      gtk_gl_area_make_current(GTK_GL_AREA(widget));
    {
      GtkAllocation allocation;
      gtk_widget_get_allocation (widget, &allocation);
      glViewport(0, 0, allocation.width, allocation.height);
    }
  return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *window,*glarea;
  gchar *info_str;

  /* Attribute list for gtkglarea widget. Specifies a
     list of Boolean attributes and enum/integer
     attribute/value pairs. The last attribute must be
     GGLA_NONE. See glXChooseVisual manpage for further
     explanation.
  */
  int attrlist[] = {
    // GGLA_RGBA,
    // GGLA_RED_SIZE,1,
    // GGLA_GREEN_SIZE,1,
    // GGLA_BLUE_SIZE,1,
    // GGLA_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    // GGLA_NONE
  };

  /* initialize gtk */
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  /* Check if OpenGL is supported. */
  // if (ggla_query() == FALSE) {
    // g_print("OpenGL not supported\n");
    // return 0;
  // }


  /* Create new top level window. */
  window = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Simple");
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);

  /* Quit form main if got delete event */
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete-event",
                   G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);


  /* Create new OpenGL widget. */
  //glarea = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_gl_area_new(attrlist));
  glarea = gtk_gl_area_new();
  /* Events for widget must be set before X Window is created */
  gtk_widget_set_events(GTK_WIDGET(glarea),
            GDK_EXPOSURE_MASK|
            GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

  init(glarea);

  /* Connect signal handlers */
  /* Redraw image when exposed. */
//  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(glarea), "draw",
//                   G_CALLBACK(draw), NULL);
//  /* When window is resized viewport needs to be resized also. */
//  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(glarea), "configure-event",
//                   G_CALLBACK(reshape), NULL);
//  /* Do initialization when widget has been realized. */
//  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(glarea), "realize",
//                   G_CALLBACK(init), NULL);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(glarea), "render",
                   G_CALLBACK(draw), NULL);
  /* When window is resized viewport needs to be resized also. */
//  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(glarea), "resize",
//                   G_CALLBACK(reshape), NULL);
  /* Do initialization when widget has been realized. */
//  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(glarea), "create-context",
//                   G_CALLBACK(init), NULL);

  /* set minimum size */
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(glarea), 100,100);

  /* put glarea into window and show it all */
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),GTK_WIDGET(glarea));
  gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(glarea));
  gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(window));

  /* vendor dependent version info string */
  // info_str = ggla_get_info();
  // g_print(info_str);
  // g_free(info_str);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```